# How to create a formula for a matrix in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Imagine a team of 3 people, a head, a senior development and a developer.  Imagine there are only 2 projects which they work on.  Each person splits his time between the 2 projects.  For example in the Excel table below, the "Head" is spending 80% of his time on Project A and 20% of his time on Project B.

Currently I apply a weighting to a project using the formula (Total % spent on Project / No of people), therefore for the below example the weight on Project A is 80+30+10 = 120 / 3 = 40.  For Project B the weight is 63.  This is a straightforward formula =sum(B3:B99) / countA(A3:A99) ... I sum and count up to row 99 as roles can be added and removed at any point and this leaves the formula generic.

| Role | Project A | Project B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Weight | 40 | 63 |
| Head | 80 | 20 |
| SDev | 30 | 70 |
| Dev | 10 | 90 |

Now the problem with the above is that in reality the roles have a weighting too, which means that the 100% of a Head role has more weight than the 100% of a Dev role.  I need to reflect this in the formula somehow.  Therefore let's assume the following role weights: Head = 3, SDev = 2, Dev = 1.  How could I work this out in a formula? The formula would need to be generic enough that I could add and remove people from the Excel sheet at any time.

Comment: so you want: `=(80*3+30*2+10)/6= 52`?  If so, you want sumproduct and sum, with a helper column of the weight.  If not then you will need to come up with the correct formula before we can help you.

Comment: @ScottCraner almost yes.  The formula would be =(80*3+30*2+10)/3 = 103 for Project A, and =(20*3+70*2+90) /3 = 97 for Project B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B3:B99,$D$3:$D$99)/ COUNTA(A3:A99)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, that's it thanks!  I didn't know about SumProduct.